# Reference several elements in a single variable

Tags: jquery, performance, variables

Lets say I have the following html:

```
<div class="city">
    <div class="building"></div>
    <div class="street"></div>
    <div class="house"></div>
</div>
<div class="city">
    <div class="building"></div>
    <div class="street"></div>
    <div class="house"></div>
</div>
```

I want to have everything in a variable, so I could do:

```
var city = $('.city'),
    building = city.find('.building'),
    street = city.find('.street'),
    house = city.find('.house');
```

Is there another way of making this somehow in a variable for making things easier?

```
var city = $('.city');
city[building = $('.building')];
city[street = $('.street')];
city[house = $('.house')];
```

So I can access later somehow like:

```
city[0]
```

or

```
city[building]
```

?

Comment: How is your second example easier than the first?

Comment: You are right in this case, but in the real case im trying to make variable names understandable so it gets complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use an object:

```
var city = {};
city.element = $('.city');
city.building = city.element.find('.building');
city.street = city.element.find('.street');
city.house = city.element.find('.house');
```

There are a variety of ways of creating that. E.g.:

```
var el = $('.city');
var city = {
    building: el.find('.building'),
    street:   el.find('.street'),
    house:    el.find('.house')
};
city.element = el; // If you need it
```

In both cases, later use is:

```
city.building.css("color", "green");       // Turn text within each building green
city.building.eq(0).css("color", "green"); // Turn the text within just the first building green
```

---

That's the literal answer to your question, but I think I'd probably structure things a bit differently. Here's how:

```
var cities = $(".city").map(function(city) {
    var $city = $(city);
    return {
        element:  $city,
        building: $city.find('.building'),
        street:   $city.find('.street'),
        house:    $city.find('.house')
    };
}).get();
```

*(Note the `.get()` at the end, it's easy to miss.)*

Then the entries are for the cities, and the properties on the city entries are specific to *that* city. With the structure above the line (the "literal answer"), you could end up with `building` having four matches but `element` having more than that (because some `.city` elements have no `.building` in them).

So to use them:

```
cities[0].building.css("color", "green");
```

Comment: Thank you, could you give me a link to some tutorial or information? All I can find are (I guess) complex objects with functions inside.

Comment: @Alvaro: You're welcome. You probably want to read a good book on JavaScript. I liked Flanagan's *JavaScript: The Definitive Guide* and I can't be alone as it's in its 6th edition now. :-) MDN offers a [page talking about objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). I write about JavaScript [on my blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/search/label/javascript) but I don't think I've done this topic specifically.

Comment: Thanks again. One last thing, how can I access the .building that belongs to an especific .city (lets say some city wont return anything because they dont have .building)? city[1].buiding , city.element[1].building doesnt seems to work.

Comment: @Alvaro: I think I would probably structure things differently if that's the case, see update above.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the selector inside `find()`:

```
var props = $('.city').find('.building, .street, .house')
```

In your case, it will return 6 elements (3 for each of elements with `.city` class), that can be accessed like `props[index]`